# R Copying to and Reading from csv Files

Tags: r, csv, formatting

When I go to save Excel data that I've pasted into a .csv file, I get a formatting issue and often the saved file has all the numbers in each row as one long string.

[image]

My read statement is

```
resids<-read.csv("C:\\Projects\residuals_Parts3.csv",header=TRUE)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you mean that you are copy & pasting data directly from Excel into a text file open in a text editor?

Comment: Could you explain the problem in more depth, e.g. also including a reproducible example of the code you are using to produce the CSV? There is not much we can do for you without being able to reproduce your situation, especially since the error message from Excel is not a big deal (formatting is always lost going from XLSX to CSV, and that's pretty much always OK.) Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you are getting is fairly standard in Excel - any formatting you've added to the file (e.g. widening columns) will get lost if you don't save the file as an excel file..  and the warning is supposed to remind you of this.  Personally, the extra click or two annoys me too.

If you would like to avoid converting excel files to CSV before bringing them into R, try the `openxls` package.  It's saved me from a lot of that monkey business.